# Typeahead in Rails: Duplicate search field in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Using Rails 5 w/ & Bootstrap 3 and `gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails', '~> 0.11.1'`:

I'm getting some odd behaviors... When I load the `root_path` page, the typeahead input field displays next to the Bootstrap input field (like this):

[root path search field displays in duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLqve.png)

But when I go to another page (for example, root_path/settings), the field displays and behaves properly (like this):

[all other paths display the navbar search field correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJQ9t.png)

Here is the form_tag code (from a Bootstrap nav):

```
      <div class="navbar-form navbar-left" >
        <%= form_tag searches_path, id: 'searchMain', method: :get do %>
          <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], placeholder: 'search', class: 'form-control typeahead' %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
           <%= submit_tag 'Search', style: 'display:none' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

Could this be caused by Turbolinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually quite elementary: I had the `id` tag to the corresponding typeahead script in the wrong place. It should be inside the `text_field_tag`.

The correct code for the Bootstrap Nav should be:

```
      <%= form_tag searches_path, method: :get do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], id: 'searchMain', placeholder: 'search', class: 'form-control typeahead' %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
        <%= submit_tag 'Search', style: 'display:none' %>
      <% end %>
```

This references the following script:

```
$('#searchMain').typeahead({
  highlight: true,
},
{
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: events.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
    header: '<h3 class="search-header">Events</h3>'
  },
});
```